# disabling keyboard pop up when pressing clear() button

Tags: flutter

I have bunch of input fields which take up the whole screen, row by row and at the end I have 'x' icon to clear the input field. While everything works fine, it's a bit clumsy, because every time you press the clear icon, keyboard pops up and takes the space of more than half the phone screen (I just want it to stay own after clicking the clear button).

I've tried to work it out with GestureDetector and few other options that I've found, upon trying to solve my problem, but haven't find anything that works.

here's a piece of code where onPressed is defined to see what's pretty much happening. You simply write in some information, but then you clear it with 'x' icon, which is triggered upon calling onPressed.. I'm not sure if there's a way to combine executing FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()); after executing dateController.clear()

```
          TextFormField(

            controller: dateController,
            validator: (value){
              if(value.isEmpty){
                return "Enter Valid Feedback";
              }else{
                return null;
              }
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Datum",
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                onPressed: () => dateController.clear(),

                icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the `stopPropogation` effect that we are used to in `html` by using `Stack` in your case.

Like this,

```
Stack(children: [
  TextFormField(
    controller: dateController,
    validator: (value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return "Enter Valid Feedback";
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: "Datum",
    ),
  ),
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        dateController.clear();
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
    ),
  ),
]),
```

Since your `IconButton` is now in a `Stack`, your `TextFormField` doesn't register the event.

Comment: Guess this would work, but I don't want to refactor most of my code.. I guess, if I don't find a more elegant solution, I'll go with yours.

Comment: Sure @user14584183. I'll do some research on it and get back to you if find something more elegant. Do considering accepting the answer if you end up going with this.

Comment: From documentation `There is no mechanism for canceling or stopping pointer events from being dispatched further.` So either using a `Stack` or a `Row` seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom `FocusNode` to control the focus of your input field. For reference, check this URL: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus. You have to set a custom FocusNode for the TextField and call the `unfocus()` method on pressing clear button.

Comment: Doesn't really work, because it's just changing state all the time, I tried onPressed: () => [dateController.clear(), FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()],.. However, I have multiple input fields and it's just changing states all the itme and popping up keyboard with the next text field I try to clear.

I'll for example press clear on date input field and it will disable the keyboard pop up, but on next text field I press clear it will focus it on again.

Answer (score 0):

```
dateController.clear();
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
```

works for me on a real android device (not tested in emulator)

Comment: Works the same as FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();, the thing is it works, but only when you click on a given text field you wanna clear.

From my own example, I have date input field and then post number input field, etc.. if I'm on post number input field and press the button to clear date input field it doesn't work. If I'm active on post number input field and press the button clear it works, but that's not what I want. I want it to work even if I'm not on active on the same input field.